# how to get push notification in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have implement the **push notification** in my application. And its work perfectly when any notification is coming. But my question is when any notification is coming to application and **user clear the push notification without open the application**. And then if user click on app icon and open the application, at that time **how can we know whether notification is there or not?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user ignores the push notification and opens the app as she/he would normally do, then your app won't tell that there is a push notification waiting. In this case, you could ask your server if there are any unread notifications (of course this requires a read/unread mechanism on the server side).